# pyModis problems on Mac

Tags: pymodis

I've installed pyModis on my Mac using `pip install pyModis`. No error messages. When I try to run `modis_download.py` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/modis_download.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pymodis import optparse_required
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymodis/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import downmodis
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymodis/downmodis.py", line 53, in <module>
    from urllib.request import urlopen
ImportError: No module named request
```

Does anyone know what's up here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `urllib` [has changed since python 3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#module-urllib) and it seems like my `pyModis` wants to use the new imports. I fixed the problem by changing urllib.request to just urllib in some parts of `downmodis.py`.